# Why am I getting a TypeScript type error in this Effector effect subscriber?

Tags: typescript, typeerror, typescript-typings, effector

I'm working on a front-end app using React, Typescript, Effector, FetchAPI and more.
I made an Effector effect to delete an item in my backend:

```
export const deleteItemFX = createEffect({
  handler: (id: string) => {
    return fetch(itemUrl + id, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
  }
})
```

Now in my React component, I import my effect and add a subscriber to its 'finally' event, as per the documentation:

```
deleteItemFX.finally.watch(({params, status, result}) => {
    console.log('finally.watch called');
    if (result.ok) {
      result.json().then(() => {
        message.success(t("delete_item.success"));
      })
    }
  });
```

My code does not compile because of the following type error:

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type '{ status: "done"; params: string; result: Response; } | { status: "fail"; params: string; error: Error; }'.  TS2339
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get the 'result' of my handler in my 'finally.watch' function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pull out the property `result` when you destructure the argument to `watch`, before you check whether `status` equals `"done"` or `"fail"`.

Look at the error message: the property `result` does not exist on the type:

```js
{ status: "done"; params: string; result: Response; }
| { status: "fail"; params: string; error: Error; }
```

This is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of two object types; to read a property from a union, that property must exist on *both* sides of the union. `result` only exists on the first case, not on the second. So before you try to read it, you need to make sure that the data you have belongs to the first case. You do this by using an `if` statement to refine the type:

```js
deleteItemFX.finally.watch(response => {
    console.log('finally.watch called');
    if (response.status === "fail") {
        // Handle error here. TypeScript knows that we're in the
        // second case of the union type here, so response.error
        // is available inside this block
        return;
    }

    // Now TypeScript knows that we're in the first case of the union,
    // and that response.result exists, so we can read it
    if (response.result.ok) {
      result.json().then(() => {
        message.success(t("delete_item.success"));
      })
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it!

Comment: Ok, I did it :)